# Getting Azure Blob With a partial name

Tags: c#, azure

I have following Azure blobs inside a container,

```
111_101.jpg
111_102.jpg
111_103.jpg
112_204.jpg
112_205.jpg
```

Now I know the first part of the image name, that is 111 or 112. Is it possible for me to take the first Image which starts from 111 or 112. ?

How can I modify the following code, when variable _image will have only the first part of the file name, that is 111.

```
            string _urlContainer = containerName;
            string _image = "111_102.jpg";

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = null;
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(_urlContainer);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(_image);            
            if (Exists(blockBlob))
            {
              return blockBlob.DownloadByteArray();
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer:
If you don't know the blob name, you have to get all blob references with `container.ListBlobs()` and then find the one, you're lokking for.

To reduce the overhead, you could use virtual directory. Name your blobs

```
111/101.jpg
111/102.jpg
111/103.jpg
112/204.jpg
112/205.jpg
```

**Note on comment from Gaurav Mantri:** it is not necessary to substitute the underscores with slashes, however I believe, that the SDKs offers methods, to work with slashes. (And maybe they have some internal optimizations, that can work more efficiently with slashes)

And you can list your blobs with `container.ListBlobs("111/", true);`

The function will only return those blobs:

```
111/101.jpg
111/102.jpg
111/103.jpg
```

And from that result, you can take the first one.

Comment: Dear @FPar thanks, I think this will be a good way to go. But one slight doubt, will this work? container.ListBlobs("111_", true);

Comment: Yes. `111_` would basically acts as a prefix and will return all blobs starting with (and greater than) this string. So it will return not only the blobs starting with `111` but also `112`. I would go with @FPar's recommendation.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav I will go ahead with this by replacing _ with /.

Comment: @GauravMantri could you please help me with that I can't get the said syntax working for container.ListBlobs , it has only two versions, the mentioned one and container.ListBlobs(BlobRequestOptions). I am unable to get the syntax container.ListBlobs("111/", true); working....

Comment: I just tried with `var blobs = container.ListBlobs("111/", true);` and it worked perfectly fine for me. Can you share your code?

Comment: @TBA Are you using a recent version of the tools?

Comment: @FPar thanks, I think it because I was using dll azure.storageclient.dll.