# Get blobs from azure storage excluding subfolders

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

Trying to get blobs from Azure storage container using CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs, but I want to only get blobs from the specific folder (using prefix), not the sub-folders under the main folder.

For example lets say I have this:

```
Folder
  Sub-Folder
    image2.jpg
  image1.jpg
```

If I use Folder as the prefix, I want to get image1.jpg AND exclude image2.jpg (anything under sub-folders)

Answer (score 0):

From [Reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/486)

If you call CloudBlobContainer.listBlobs() method,it will by default return a list of BlobItems that contains the blobs and directories immediately under the container. It's the default behavior with v8.

Even if you want to match pattern ,As mentioned by @Gaurav mantri- [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076452/pattern-search-in-azure-blob-file-names)

> There's limited support for server-side searching in Azure Blob
> Storage. Only thing you can filter on is the blob prefix i.e. you can
> instruct Azure Storage service to only returns blobs names of which
> start with certain characters.

But if you want to get based on file name ,below example might give an idea

```
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
foreach (var file in container.ListBlobs(prefix: " Folder/filename.xml", useFlatBlobListing: true))
{ …}
```

In your case try with  Folder/filename.jpg.

> Note:
>
> 1. useFlatBlobListing: Setting this value to true will ensure that only blobs are returned (including inside any sub folders inside that
>    directory) and not directories and blobs.
> 2. So, if you only want blobs, you have to set the UseFlatBlobListing property option to true.

Other references:
[Ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113667/getting-azure-blob-with-a-partial-name),[ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308875/how-is-the-prefix-parameter-used-in-cloudblobcontainer-listblobs-to-get-files)