# Get folder name in Azure container

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

In my Azure storage account, I have a container named `"testcontainer"`. Inside it, there are two folders named `"DATA_FILE_A"` and `"DATA_FILE_B"`. I would want to get all the folder names. (i.e. `"DATA_FILE_A"` and `"DATA_FILE_B"`). Then based on the folder name, I do a checking to see if the folder name starts with `"DATA_FILE_"`. If so, then I get into that folder and get all the files of this folder. My questions are:

1. How to get all the folder names ? (i.e. `"DATA_FILE_A" and "DATA_FILE_B"`)
2. How to get all the files of a specified folder ?

   ```
    CloudStorageAccount c = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connStr);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = c.createCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("testcontainer");

    Iterable<ListBlobItem> directoryList = container.listBlobs();
   ```

If there is only one folder, I could get the file, but for getting all folders I got confused.

```
CloudStorageAccount c = CloudStorageAccount.parse(connStr);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = c.createCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("testcontainer");
CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.getDirectoryReference("DATA_FILE_A");

Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = directory.listBlobs();

for (ListBlobItem item : blobs) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CloudBlockBlob b = (CloudBlockBlob) item;
    b.download(output);
    //further processing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/486), if you call CloudBlobContainer.listBlobs() method,it will by default return a list of BlobItems that contains the blobs and directories immediately under the container. It's the default behavior with v8.
Pattern match might not be supported ,As mentioned by @Gaurav mantri in  [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076452/pattern-search-in-azure-blob-file-names)

> There's limited support for server-side searching in Azure Blob
> Storage. Only thing you can filter on is the blob prefix i.e. you can
> instruct Azure Storage service to only returns blobs names of which
> start with certain characters. But if you want to get based on file
> name ,below example might give an idea i.e; you may give a try with

```
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = myCloudBlobContainer.listBlobs("Directory", true);
```

Or

```
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
foreach (var file in container.ListBlobs(prefix: " Folder / ", useFlatBlobListing: true))
{ …}
```

Ex: foreach (var file in container.ListBlobs(prefix: " Data/File/ ", useFlatBlobListing: true))
{ …}

Please check these  [Ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113667/getting-azure-blob-with-a-partial-name), [Ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308875/how-is-the-prefix-parameter-used-in-cloudblobcontainer-listblobs-to-get-files)

> Note:
>
> 1. useFlatBlobListing: Setting this value to true will ensure that only blobs are returned (including inside any sub folders inside that
>    directory) and not directories and blobs.
> 2. So, if you only want blobs, you have to set the UseFlatBlobListing property option to true.